# How to validate kendo DateTimePickerFor using mvc 4 razor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i wants to validate kendo DateTimePickerFor on client side.My control on view as

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m.StartDate)
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px", @class = datePicker",required = "true" })
                        .Name("StartDate")
                        .Depth(CalendarView.Year)
                        .Value(DateTime.Now.ToString())
                        .Min(DateTime.Now.ToString())
                        .Max(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4))
                        .Format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")                        

                )
```

i have masked it in ready function.but it allows me to type any input.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datePicker').mask('99/99/9999');

    $('#_appointmentCreateForm input[type="text"], textarea').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom',
        onlyOne: false,
        position: 'right',
        appendTo: "#_appointmentCreateForm"
    });

    $('#_appointmentCreateForm').validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {

            StartDate: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {

            StartDate: {
                required: "Please choose Date and Time."
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: ValidatorErrorPlacement,
        success: ValidatorSuccess
    }
    );

});
```

And when there is no value in datetimepicker i.e datetimepicker is empty then validation gets fail but not showing any message.
So, any ideas how I can validate the Kendo DateTimePicker to accept valid input format? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved!when i changed my ready function to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datePicker').mask('99/99/9999');

    $('#_appointmentCreateForm input[type="text"], textarea').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom',
        onlyOne: false,
        position: 'right',
        appendTo: "#_appointmentCreateForm"
    });

    $('#_appointmentCreateForm').validate({
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            Speciality: {
                selectspeciality: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Speciality: {
                selectspeciality: "Please select Speciality."
            }

        },
        errorPlacement: ValidatorErrorPlacement,
        success: ValidatorSuccess
    }
    );



    $.validator.addMethod("selectspeciality", function (value, element) {
        var isValid = $(element).data("kendoDropDownList").selectedIndex == 0 ? false : true;
        return this.optional(element) || isValid;
    }, "Please select Speciality.");
});
```

Ho[e it will help someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

You can define

```
    Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.date_debut)
    .ParseFormats(new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" })
```

on the control. But this will be a server side validate as Html.Kendo() will generate the control from the model.
To validate it in client side, the best way is to test when the submit is fired.

```
$.submit(function(e) {
 //test if form is ok
});
```